# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call with append

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have the following code, where it seems I'm using `append` in a wrong way, since I'm getting: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

```
i = 0
distance = []    
distance.append(i) = measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Do you mean `distance.append(measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2))` ?

Comment: that downvote would be too harsh isn't it?

Comment: What you are tring to do it the same as `distance  = [measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2)]`,  what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to insert the result of `measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2)` at `i` position, you should do -

```
distance.insert(i, measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2))
```

If you want to append the result to the end, you should instead do -

```
distance.append(measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2))
```

Answer (score 2):

either use

```
i=0
distance = []    
distance.insert(i,measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2)
```

or use

```
distance = []    
distance.append(measureDistance.Distance2BetweenPoints(p1, p2))
```